# Destructuring not working with req.* in express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just trying to pull values off of the `req.headers` and can't seem to do it if I destructure them.

Here is my code:

```js
export default function(req, res, next) {
    const { headers } = req
    Object.keys(headers).forEach(key => {
        console.log(`${key}: ${headers[key]}`)
        // has apiKey and sanityKey logged out with values
    })
    const apiKey = headers[`apiKey`]
    const sanityKey = headers.sanityKey

    console.log(apiKey, sanityKey) // both are undefined

    const isValid = apiKey === process.env.X_API_KEY
    if(isValid && sanityKey) {
        req.apiKey = apiKey
        if(sanityKey) req.sanityKey = sanityKey
        next()
    } else {  
        res.status(403).send({
            message: `You must send an apiKey and sanityKey through the headers.`,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: `apiKey` and `sanityKey` aren't compliant header names and also node lowercases all header names. Can you please share more output?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It very much does exist. Express' `req` object is an extension of node's [IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) class which does have a headers property.

Comment: my bad, forgot about the underlying Node class. As Aplet123 mentions: can you show the actual logged text?

Comment: Do you want to share some of that logging info? Because node lowercases headers by default and apiKey isn't a good header name.

Comment: It was the lowercase. I completely forgot it was parsed to that. Been doing react for 2 years and happened to do some express today after 2 years, I'm a bit rusty. Thank you @Aplet123

Comment: Why don't you just use `const apiKey = req.getHeader("apiKey")` and `const sanityKey = req.getHeader("sanityKey")`.  That takes care of everything here for you automatically as it handles case insensitive matching for you automatically and it doesn't need destructuring at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue with destructuring.  It's an issue with case matching.  Because header matching is supposed to be case insensitive matching, the preferred way to retrieve a header is `req.getHeader("apiKey")` as that will take care of the case insensitive match for you.

To facilitate that case insensitive matching the property names on the `req.headers` object are all lowercase, thus your mixed case property names always return `undefined`.  Your original code would likely work if you just used lowercase property names, but `req.getHeader()` is the preferred implementation.

So, here's what I would suggest:

```
export default function(req, res, next) {
    const apiKey = req.getHeader("apiKey");
    const sanityKey = req.getHeader("sanityKey");

    console.log(apiKey, sanityKey);

    const isValid = apiKey === process.env.X_API_KEY
    if(isValid && sanityKey) {
        req.apiKey = apiKey
        if(sanityKey) req.sanityKey = sanityKey
        next()
    } else {  
        res.status(403).send({
            message: `You must send an apiKey and sanityKey through the headers.`,
        })
    }
}
```